# Expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token G++

Tags: c++, gcc, expression, token

GCC keeps telling me:

> expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token,
>   expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
>   expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token

And I could not find the problem. Here is the function that have the problem:

```
void prim(){
    prepararEstructuras();
    int min,k;  
    for(int i=1;i<nnodos;i++){
        min = menorCoste[1];
        k = 1;
        for(int j=2;i<nnodos;j++)
            if(menorCoste[j] < min){
                min = menorCoste[j];
                k = j;
            }
        solucion[k][masCercano[k]] = G[k][masCercano[k]];
        menorCoste[k] = infinito;
        for(int j=1;j<nnodos;j++)
            if(G[k][j] < menorCoste[j] && menorCoste[j]!=infinito){
                menorCoste[j] = G[k][j];
                masCercano[j] = k;
            }                   
    }
}
```

Here is the line that cause the problem:

```
if(G[k][j] < menorCoste[j] && menorCoste[j]!=infinito){
```

And here are my variables:

```
#define MAX_NODOS 20000
#define infinito 10000;

int nnodos;
int nAristas;
int G[MAX_NODOS][MAX_NODOS]; 
int solucion[MAX_NODOS][MAX_NODOS];
int menorCoste[MAX_NODOS];
int masCercano[MAX_NODOS];
```

Comment: What effect does this macro have on that line? #define infinito 10000;

Comment: While what you have is valid, I highly suggest putting those `{}` around those multi-line `for` loops, it's more difficult to read and easier to mess things up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon in your macro.

```
#define infinito 10000;
                      ^
```

Get rid of it.

As it is, your line gets expanded to this:

```
if(G[k][j] < menorCoste[j] && menorCoste[j]!=10000;){
                                                  ^ does not belong here
```

Alternatively, don't use macros at all:

```
const int MAX_NODOS = 20000;
const int infinito = 10000;
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer is accpeted

Comment: Though, you really should read about preprocessor vs. actual C Code - to understand why such an innocent additional semi-colon ****** your code up ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please, learn to use a GOOD STYLE. Omitting brackets in outer statements (e.g. statements that contain other statements) is an **extraordinarily BAD style**.

However, your actual bug lies in some pre-processor statement and its resulting code: `#define infinito 10000;` results in an extra semi-colon in-between an expression where you do not expect such an additional expression. Particularly where you will not expect a semi-colon at all.

Comment: What can only be worse style is giving something called infinito a set value.